# Embed pickle (or arbitrary) data in python script

Tags: python, embed

In Perl, the interpreter kind of stops when it encounters a line with

```
__END__
```

in it. This is often used to embed arbitrary data at the end of a perl script. In this way the perl script can fetch and store data that it stores 'in itself', which allows for quite nice opportunities.

In my case I have a pickled object that I want to store somewhere. While I can use a file.pickle file just fine, I was looking for a more compact approach (to distribute the script more easily).

Is there a mechanism that allows for embedding arbitrary data inside a python script somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the data is not particularly large (many K) I would just .encode('base64') it and include that in a triple-quoted string, with .decode('base64') to get back the binary data, and a pickle.loads() call around it.

Comment: Why base64 encode it when pickle.dumps() outputs ASCII by default already?

Comment: Lester, multiple reasons. Have you tried it with binary data? It's much larger because of all the escaping. Also the Python 2.x str.encode() routine formats it in nice lines for you, to keep the source file tidy.  (Under 3.x you can't encode to base64 with str.encode but there is a base64 module. Looks like maybe the nice formatting requires custom code now though. Note also that under 3.x pickle.dumps() outputs a bytes type by default, not string, though that's probably not in itself a problem.)

Comment: Fair enough - I would be too concern about size until I am having performance issues ;-)

Comment: "Much larger" is already a performance issue. I know all about "premature optimization"; this one isn't premature.

Answer (score 4):

With pickle you can also work directly on strings.

```
s = pickle.dumps(obj)
pickle.loads(s)
```

If you combine that with """ (triple-quoted strings) you can easily store any pickled data in your file.

Answer (score 2):

In Python, you can use """ (triple-quoted strings) to embed long runs of text data in your program.

In your case, however, don't waste time on this.

If you have an object you've pickled, you'd be much, much happier dumping that object as Python source and simply including the source.

The `repr` function, applied to most objects, will emit a Python source-code version of the object.  If you implement `__repr__` for all of your custom classes, you can trivially dump your structure as Python source.

If, on the other hand, your pickled structure started out as Python code, just leave it as Python code.

Comment: Too clarify at little (I think): Just make the class `__repr__()` method emit the Python source code for a valid call to the class's `__init__()` method that will reconstruct the instance being saved.

Answer (score 2):

I made this code.  You run something like python comp.py foofile.tar.gz, and it creates decomp.py, with foofile.tar.gz's contents embedded in it.  I don't think this is really portable with windows because of the Popen though.

```
import base64
import sys
import subprocess

inf = open(sys.argv[1],"r+b").read()
outs = base64.b64encode(inf)

decomppy = '''#!/usr/bin/python
import base64

def decomp(data):
    fname = "%s"
    outf = open(fname,"w+b")
    outf.write(base64.b64decode(data))
    outf.close()

    # You can put the rest of your code here.
    #Like this, to unzip an archive
    #import subprocess
    #subprocess.Popen("tar xzf " + fname, shell=True)
    #subprocess.Popen("rm " + fname, shell=True)
''' %(sys.argv[1])

taildata = '''uudata = """%s"""
decomp(uudata)
''' %(outs)

outpy = open("decomp.py","w+b")
outpy.write(decomppy)
outpy.write(taildata)
outpy.close()
subprocess.Popen("chmod +x decomp.py",shell=True)
```

Comment: +1 I believe this would be fairly easy to convert to the Windows platform. Nice idea.