# Exporting plot with full data or saving as a script

Tags: python, python-3.x, export, matplotlib, graphing

I'm using python with matplotlib to create plots out of data, an I'd like to save this plots on a pdf file (but I could use also a more specific format).
I'm using basically this instructions:

```
plt.plot(data)
figname = ''.join([filename, '_', label, '.pdf'])
plt.savefig(figname)
```

But what this does is create an image of the plot with the zoom in which it's displayed; I would like to create a copy that shows all points (>10000) that I'm plotting so I would be able to zoom to any level.
Which is the correct way to do that?

EDIT: is there a format (such as '.fig' for Matlab) that calls directly the viewer of Matplotlib with the data i saved?
Maybe it's possible to create a .py script that saves the points and that i can call to quickly re-display them? I think that this is what is done by the .fig Matlab file.

[image: This is the detail of the plot exported as pdf]

[image: And this is what I would like to obtain, still being able to see the whole plot, that is bigger]

Comment: `'%s_%s.pdf' % (filename, label)`

Comment: i used that method because label is usually a list of strings, depending on how many curves i plot in the same graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any native Matplotlib file format which includes your data; in fact, I'm not sure the Matploblib objects even have a write function defined.

What I do instead to simulate the Matlab .fig concept is to save the processed data (as a numpy array, or pickled) and run a separate .py script to recreate the Matplotlib plots.

So in steps:

1. Process your data and make some pretty plots until you are fully content
2. Save/pickle your processed data as close to the plot commands as possible (you might even want to store the data going into a histogram if making the histogram takes a long time)
3. Write a new script in which you import the data and copy/paste the plotting commands from the original script

It is a bit clumsy, but it works. If you really want, you could embed the pickled data as a string in your plotting script ([Embed pickle (or arbitrary) data in python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887968/embed-pickle-or-arbitrary-data-in-python-script)). This gives you the benefit of working with a single python script containing both the data as well as the plotting code.

### Edit

You can check for the existence of your stored processed data file and skip the processing steps if this file exists. So:

```
if not processed_data.file exists:
   my_data = process_raw_data()
else:
   my_data = read_data_from_file(processed_data.file)

plot(my_data)
```

In this way, you can have one script for both creating the graph in the first place, and re-plotting the graph using pre-processed data.

You might want to add a runtime argument for forcing a re-processing of the data in case you change something to the processing script and don't want to manually remove your processed data file.

Comment: And (sorry but i'm still newbie with python) can i create a python script from another in a way that i can call it just double-clicking? Because i have to do this for many files, and creating every time the script would require too much time.

Comment: Maybe there is a function tha store a variable (list) in a file and one for restoring it, mantaining the same structure? I know how to do it with a .csv file, but there isn't a more straightforward way?

Comment: Well, there's the 'pickle' concept, or if you have numpy arrays you can use numpy.save. Same way you can save and load Matlab variables. Not sure what you mean with 'Because I have to do this for many files'; is it the same script for different input data, or do you have hundreds of different scripts creating different figures with no common elements?

Comment: Yes i think it's the latter: i have many sets of data and i have to create multiple plots of them, so if there is a way for dinamically create these scripts, it would be great.

Comment: Use one script and check for the existence of the processed data (see edit above)

Answer (score 1):

Use `plt.xlim` and `plt.ylim` to set the domain and range.
Set `figsize` to indirectly control the pixel resolution of the final image. (`figsize` sets the size of the figure in inches; the default dpi is 100.)
You can also control the `dpi` in the call to `plt.savefig`.

With `figsize = (10, 10)` and `dpi = 100`, the image will have resolution `1000x1000`.

---

For example,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x, y = np.random.random((2,10000))
plt.plot(x, y, ',')
figname = '/tmp/test.pdf'
xmin, xmax = 0, 1
ymin, ymax = 0, 1
plt.xlim(xmin, xmax)
plt.ylim(ymin, ymax)
plt.savefig(figname)
```

Your pdf viewer should be able to zoom in any region so individual points can be distinguished.

Comment: thank you for telling me about xlim and ylim, i was looking also for that :) but what i need is the possibility to save the plot at a resolution that allows me to see the single points. With this implementation, i have only the shape of the plot but the real resolution of the plot is lost.

Comment: You can control the resolution by setting the `figsize` and/or `dpi` parameters. I've edited my answer to show what I mean.

Comment: i think that it doesn't make the difference, because i'm plotting in a vector format (pdf); what i would like is to save the points, more than a bare image