# Python: Save pickled object in the python script

Tags: python, pickle

I have a class instance which I dump in a .pickle file using `pickle.dump(instance,outputfile)` . I can distribute the script and the pickle file and ask users to run the python script with the pickle file as an argument, and then I can load that instance using `pickle.load(pickle_file_passed_as_argument)`

Can I instead "embed" the pickle file inside the script itself, and then just pass the script around? Then, when users run the script I can load the instance of the "embedded" object and use all the object's member functions?

My question is similar to:

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887968/embed-pickle-or-arbitrary-data-in-python-script)

I didn't understand any of the answers given there as they're abstract descriptions of what to do, without code examples. I'm not sure how to use the triple-quote trick to embed objects (though all the answers in that question mention that). I've not used triple-quote strings like that before..

One of the answers mentions using `s=pickle.dumps(objectInstance)` followed by `pickle.loads(s)` and combine that with the triple quotes to embed the object. How exactly do I "combine" dumps,loads with the triple quotes trick, I don't get that part..

Comment: Why don't you just embed the object as ordinary Python code (e.g. by using `repr` to dump Python code for the instance)? It will be clearer than a giant pickle blob in your code.

Comment: @nneonneo Can you illustrate an example of doing that?.. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887968/embed-pickle-or-arbitrary-data-in-python-script) means is to encode the data to be included with `pickle` and `encode`:

```
import pickle
data = dict(a=1,b=2)
pickle.dumps(data).encode('base64')

> 'KGRwMApTJ2EnCnAxCkkxCnNTJ2InCnAyCkkyCnMu\n'
```

and to decode it accordingly in your file to be shared from the string being written in the source code:

```
import pickle
# data encoded as a string
encoded_data = """KGRwMApTJ2EnCnAxCkkxCnNTJ2InCnAyCkkyCnMu\n"""

# decoding of the data
data = pickle.loads(encoded_data.decode('base64'))
print data

> {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```